# Similar concepts to Cells and Atoms in Hindu texts

Tags: vaishnavism, yoga, science

Curious if there are any concepts similar to cells and atoms in Hindu text especially those with either vaishnava or yoga links. I wish to know more about Hindu concepts on Prakriti in this way and compare and contrast with modern scientific theories.

Comment: There are multiple texts on atoms, I remember in Nyaya, Mimsa school explaining Maya. For the cells part, it is a part of annamaya kosha (Taittariya Upanishad), followed by pranamaya kosha (prakriti). This has been extensively documented by Adi Shankaracharya.

Comment: > *I wish to know more about Hindu concepts on Prakriti in this way and compare and contrast with modern scientific theories.*

If you want to know about the Hindu concepts that align well with scientific theories - evolution, illusion, big bang, etc from fields of cosmology to neurology, then you should be looking at *Advaita Vedanta*, while it is not *Vaishnavism*-centric, but all claimed avatars in Vaishnavism are Advaitic after *Varaha* avatar. For example - Erwin Schrodinger was himself Advait.

Comment: @Abhas Kumar Sinha that's more like the gross body rather than cells. I mean as in cells like a basic unit of self sustenance.

Comment: in that case sorry. The Hindu metaphysics never needed to dig into the individual cells, the best they had were the kosha system and the constituents of the kosha system - like earth, water, air, fire, etc. from which the body has been made. This is again discussed in Advaita Upanishad: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sariraka_Upanishad

Comment: kk interesting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bhagavatam provides a philosophical and cosmological explanation for the existence of paramāṇus within the context of its narrative and teachings. It is not intended to be a scientific treatise in the way modern scientific theories are developed and tested through empirical observation and experimentation.

It's important to approach ancient religious and philosophical texts with an understanding of their cultural and historical context. The descriptions found in texts like the Bhagavatam are often symbolic, allegorical, or metaphysical, reflecting the worldview and philosophical concepts of the time in which they were composed.

While the Bhagavatam and modern science both explore the nature of the universe, they do so using different methodologies and assumptions, and it's crucial to appreciate these distinctions.

When I mention that descriptions in texts like the Bhagavatam are often symbolic, allegorical, or metaphysical, I am referring to the fact that these texts often use language and imagery that go beyond literal, straightforward representation. Here's a breakdown of these terms:

Symbolic: Symbolism involves the use of symbols to represent ideas, qualities, or concepts. In religious and philosophical texts, symbols are often employed to convey deeper meanings that may not be easily expressed through literal language. For example, in the Bhagavatam, the description of paramāṇus (subtle particles) may symbolize the foundational elements of the material world, emphasizing the idea of indivisibility and subtlety.

Allegorical: Allegory is a form of storytelling or expression in which characters, events, or elements represent abstract ideas or moral qualities. The Bhagavatam, like many ancient religious texts, contains allegorical elements that convey spiritual or philosophical truths through narrative. The stories and teachings may have deeper, symbolic meanings that go beyond a literal interpretation.

Metaphysical: Metaphysics deals with abstract concepts that go beyond the physical or observable realm. In religious and philosophical texts, metaphysical discussions often explore the nature of reality, existence, and the relationship between the material and spiritual realms. The Bhagavatam contains metaphysical discussions about the nature of the self (ātman), the Supreme Reality (Brahman), and the material world.

In the context of the Bhagavatam's cosmology, the descriptions of the creation of the universe, the nature of the elements, and the concept of paramāṇus are not intended to provide scientific explanations in the way modern science does. Instead, they serve as a means to convey profound spiritual and philosophical insights, using symbolic and allegorical language to communicate truths that may transcend literal interpretation.

Understanding these aspects helps readers approach ancient texts with a nuanced perspective, appreciating the richness of the symbolic and allegorical layers that contribute to the overall depth of the teachings. It's also essential to recognize the cultural and historical context in which these texts were composed, as worldviews and philosophical frameworks can vary significantly across different times and cultures.

Comment: Thanks why does it sound like ChatGPT wrote this however.

Comment: Good catch @Haridasa. In my opinion, this answer has a lot of words but barely says anything.

Answer (score 0):

**bhagavatapurANa book 3 chapter 11** talks about theory of atoms & molecules :

> *maitreya uvāca caramaḥ sad-viśeṣāṇām aneko ’saṁyutaḥ sadā paramāṇuḥ sa vijñeyo nṛṇām aikya-bhramo yataḥ ...1*
>
> *The material manifestation’s ultimate particle, which is indivisible and not formed into a body, is called the atom. It exists always as an
> invisible identity, even after the dissolution of all forms. The
> material body is but a combination of such atoms, but it is
> misunderstood by the common man.*
>
> *sata eva padārthasya svarūpāvasthitasya yat kaivalyaṁ parama-mahān aviśeṣo nirantaraḥ ...2*
>
> *Atoms are the ultimate state of the manifest universe. When they stay in their own forms without forming different bodies, they are called
> the unlimited oneness. There are certainly different bodies in
> physical forms, but the atoms themselves form the complete
> manifestation.*
>
> *evaṁ kālo ’py anumitaḥ saukṣmye sthaulye ca sattama saṁsthāna-bhuktyā bhagavān avyakto vyakta-bhug vibhuḥ ...3*
>
> *One can estimate time by measuring the movement of the atomic combination of bodies. Time is the potency of bhagavan, who controls
> all physical movement although He is not visible in the physical
> world.*
>
> *sa kālaḥ paramāṇur vai yo bhuṅkte paramāṇutām sato ’viśeṣa-bhug yas tu sa kālaḥ paramo mahān ...4*
>
> *Atomic time is measured according to its covering a particular atomic space. That time which covers the unmanifest aggregate of atoms is
> called the great time.*
>
> *aṇur dvau paramāṇū syāt trasareṇus trayaḥ smṛtaḥ jālārka-raśmy-avagataḥ kham evānupatann agāt ...5*
>
> *The division of gross time is calculated as follows: two atoms make one double atom, and three double atoms make one hexatom. This hexatom
> is visible in the sunshine which enters through the holes of a window
> screen. One can clearly see that the hexatom goes up towards the sky.*

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: Similair theory in vishnu purana or mahabharta. Or that of Brahma and Nyaya sutras?

Comment: vaiśeṣika sūtra also has atomic theory

Comment: what about the ithihasas?